Is there Swift 6 number formatting in string interpolation without "import Foundation"?
I like being able to do this:
print( "\("YYYY") \(454.90008)" ) 

but I want to do this:
print( "\("YYYY") \(String(format: "%.3f", 454.90008))" ) 

which will only compile with import Foundation
Is that correct or is there some Swift 6 numeric precision formatting that does not require Foundation?

This is a strange question to ask. Is there something preventing you from using Foundation?

@Sweeper : linux console app with no other imports, so I'm trying to make it simple and clean. (I've noticed that things have changed from version to version, and hoped I was now mistaken.)

You can import Foundation on Linux too. It should come with your Swift installation.

Yes, and I would prefer not too.

And why is that? You can import Glibc to get the C standard library, which probably has some string formatting APIs, but obviously using them could be a pain since they are not designed specifically for Swift.

@Sweeper ; "And why is that?" The import changes what type checks. I want tighter control over dependencies. Where did yesterdays answer disappear to?

The answer by Leo Dabus was deleted by its author, probably because he realised that formatted is also part of Foundation after you pointed out to him that it doesn't't work. I'm not sure what you mean by "changes what type checks", but the bottom line is you either use a C function or roll your own.

@Sweeper : That confirmation is all I was asking for.

Doing precision formatting while not importing Foundation is hard. I don't know why you don't want to import it, it's named Foundation and it is the foundation (not all of it). But you can create a custom implementation:
extension String {
    init(_ formatting: Double, precision: Int) {
        let string = String(formatting)
        
        precondition(precision >= 0, "Precision must be a positive number")
        
        let firstHalf = string.prefix { $0 != "." }
        var secondHalf = string
            .drop { $0 != "." }
            .prefix(precision + 1)
        
        secondHalf.popFirst()
        
        if secondHalf.count < precision {
            for _ in 0..<precision - secondHalf.count {
                secondHalf.append("0")
            }
        }
        
        self.init(stringLiteral: firstHalf + (secondHalf.isEmpty ? "" : ".")  + secondHalf)
    }
}

I used precondition to guard against negative numbers. It crashes even if you don't put precondition there. But you can also early exit via guard statement depending on your implementation.
guard precision >= 0 else {
    self.init(stringLiteral: "") 
    return
 }

